# How can we run an android app in Windows at any browser?

Tags: android, mobile, apk, emulation

I want to run an android app(apk) in Windows at any browser like chrome, firefox but I do not know how.I don't want to use any emulator like bluestacks or NoxPlayer.Me. I want to run and display the application like in chrome browser at developer mode(mobile or tablet view). For example I want to add a link in any web browser to promote the applications I created so that the user can see them for example in a portfolio. I have tried to use a method like this website(https://www.androidguys.com/tips-tools/run-android-apps-chrome/) but it not working!So how can I run this and display with mobile view at any browsers in Windows? Did anyone try this?

Comment: Android apps don't work in web browsers. In the end the tool you have linked is also an emulator. But it emulates a very old device abpnd most likely has other limitations it won't work for you.

Comment: Hello Robert, I have tried another tool like emulators or extensions in chrome browser but it is not working.Thanks about your answer.